# How do I say "It's all about the marketing"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I've tried googling it up, but to no direct success.
Google translate suggests

> Es geht nur um die Vermarktung.
>
> or
>
> Es ist alles über die Vermarktung

Is any one of that correct? I'm a little confused with the noun choice, for one thing. Also, there seems to be a parallel text of

> Jetzt geht’s um die Wurst! = It’s all about the sausage now!

So, does

> Geht's um das Marketing

convey the meaning and not sound awkward? Also, is it Nominative or Genitive? What's happening here, grammatically?

Comment: I'd suggest "Es dreht sich alles (nur) ums Marketing.", which literally sets the marketing into the center of considerations. Marketing is not translated in economic speech anymore.

Comment: Does the bracketed "nur" mean the difference between "it's all *only* about the marketing" and the same without the "only"? Also, could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is

> Es dreht sich alles (nur) ums Marketing

1) Marketing is literally set into the center of considerations, just like “it’s all about”

2) The *nur* is a possible emphasis, so that it is not only in the center of considerations, but in fact the only thing that really matters. A way of thinking presumably normal in current economics.

3) Marketing could be translated, but it is not common anymore in economic context.

But it can also be understood (with or without *nur*) as a ranting surrender to reality, depending on pronunciation and context (just like in English, I presume).

Answer (score 2):

> Es geht nur um die Vermarktung

ist schon in Ordnung, wobei *Marketing* heute ein allgemeinverständliches Fremdwort ist, das man so übernehmen kann.

Manchmal passt sicherlich auch *Image* was natürlich nicht weniger ein Fremdwort ist.

> Es geht nur ums Ansehen
>
> um Äußerlichkeiten
>
> um die Fassade

wären weitere Alternativen.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for a translation would be

> "Marketing ist alles!"

As for your suggestion: "Geht's um das Marketing." sounds more like a question to me - the verb is in first position, the subject ("'s") in second. You could say "Es geht um das Marketing." to make it a normal sentence. Depending on what you would like to express, you'll also have to add a modal adverb like "ausschließlich":

> "Es geht ausschließlich ums Marketing."

But this sentence lacks the quality of "smugness" implied in the English original, IMO (but I could be wrong here, and a lot depends on context).

Apart from that, *das Marketing* is neither Nominativ nor Genitiv, but Akkusativ in this case.